# how to change onlick event of a button depending on what page user is on

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to be able to toggle between the start page and the high scores page of my game with the same button, but i'm not sure what kind of loop to use. my current code is cumbersome and ends up taking the user back to the start page with a dead high scores link. [picture of game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw2UZ.jpg)

```
highScores.on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    contentDiv.html(highScoresDiv);
    highScores.text("Back to Game");
    highScores.on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
      contentDiv.html(startDiv.html());
      containerDiv.attr("style", "text-align: center");
      highScores.text("View High Scores");
      })
})
```

Comment: Paste your code in your question instead of pasting link to a picture of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use two buttons and depending on the event (click) you enable one and disable the other. With a flag.For example in angular you can use something like the * ngIf inside the html.

```
<button *ngIf="flag" (click)="function1()">Start</button>
<button *ngIf="!flag" (click)="function2()">Back to Game</button>

funcion1(){
 //Start code
  this.flag = !this.flag;

}
funcion2(){
 //Back to game code
  this.flag = !this.flag;

}
```

Comment: i'm using jquery so the back to game button doesn't exist in my html, i created it in the javascript file